# Help with function question $f(2x + 1) = 2f(x) + 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working on this question for a few hours but I can't figure out the answer.

$f(2x + 1) = 2f(x) + 1$ for all $x$ and $f(0) = 2$ what does $f(3)$ equal?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: edited. "its what does f(3) equal?" sorry about that.

Comment: We are told that $f(0)=2$ and we are told that $f(2\cdot \color{blue}{0}+1)=2f(\color{blue}{0})+1$ so... we now can know what $f(1)$ is equal to.  Continue.

Answer (score 6):

Well, $f(3)=f(2\cdot 1+1)=2f(1)+1$. Now, $f(1)=f(2\cdot 0+1)=2f(0)+1=5$. Thus $f(3)=11$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @BLobyBlob No problem. The key to these things it toying around with the equations for a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

You have $$ f(2x+1) = 2f(x)+1$$

Let $$x=0$$ to get  $$f(1)= 2f(0)+1 = 2(2)+1 =5$$

Let $x=1$ to get $$f(3)= 2f(1)+1 = 2(5)+1 =11$$

Answer (score -3):

iteration speed of outside function is the same as inside function just they don't start with the same initial values F"Inside" starts with initial value of 0 and f"outside" starts with the initial value of 2 so you just solve for first order non homogenous recurrence relation of the form F(c+1)=2F(c)+1, with the seeds FI(0)=0, FO(0)=2. FI(t)=2^t-1, FO(t)=3*2^t-1, putting it in the form of parametric curve we get [FI(t),FO(t)], and solving for it as form of y(x). FI inverse of tI(x) =
log base 2(x+1). 2^log base 2(x+1)=x+1, 3(x+1)-1=3x+2.
so your final answer is 3x+2. checking 3(2x+1)+2=6x+3+2=6x+5.
2(3x+2)+1=6x+4+1=6x+5.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to format the math properly in your answer to make it more readable. Take a look at [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) page.